# How do I set default console background/foreground colors?

Tags: linux, debian

I have to administrate a few dozen Linux Debian boxes with PuTTY (occasionally also with Terminal on MacOS). Typically, after a few hours of work there are lots of console windows open.

I would like to configure each box to use a different (random) background color so that there is a strong visual feedback on which system I am typing at any particular time. I simply want to avoid mistakes like copying data from the test system onto the production system, instead of the other way round.

Please advise how to set up the system so that the default console background/foreground color can be defined. 
I know how to do that in the PuTTY configuration however I need this set on the system itself as I do not want to have a special PuTTY configuration for each system, also it should work exactly the same on the MacOS X Terminal.

Comment: As an aside, have you looked at setting $PS1 (your shell prompt) to include $HOSTNAME ?

Comment: yes, it is already set like this, but it is not prominent enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the systems I have to hand putty identifies itself as an xterm. This basically gives you 8 colours to play with

You can set the background colour of  with

```
tput setab n; tput clear
```

where n is 0-7. You can extend this by changing the value of $TERM so

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

will allow 256 colours 0-255.

For some backgrounds you'll definitely want to change the foreground colour use

```
tput setaf n ; tput clear
```

again n is terminal type dependant.

The command `reset` is handy when playing with the colour combinations.

Comment: another question - after running certain commands that also use color such as "top" or "ls -l --color=auto" the background color is back to the previous default. Any way to make it permanent?

Comment: You could redirect the output of your tput command to a file, then copy that into your .bashrc as the start of the PS1= statement.  That way, every time your prompt returns, the xterm is told to reset the colors.

I'd also pick a consistent color for each server that is **not** "random", but lets you associate that color with that server.

Answer (score 1):

I define this bash function, then call it to generate the command-line options for RXVT.

```bash
ForegroundBackground () 
{ 
  R1=$((RANDOM % 255));
  G1=$((RANDOM % 255));
  B1=$((RANDOM % 255));
  R2=255;
  G2=255;
  B2=255;
  CR=$((255-R1));
  CG=$((255-G1));
  CB=$((255-B1));
  BBG=$(( ( R1 * 299 + G1 * 587 + B1 * 114 ) / 1000));
  if [[ $BBG -gt 125 ]]; then
    R2=0;
    B2=0;
    G2=0;
  fi;
  printf -- "-bg #%02x%02x%02x -fg #%02x%02x%02x -cr #%02x%02x%02x\n" $R1 $G1 $B1 $R2 $G2 $B2 $CR $CG $CB;
}
```